# Protect a Symfony2 Controller's action from unauthorized requests with an Annotation

Tags: php, python, symfony, annotations, decorator

I can't seem to find out if it is possible to protect a `Controller's` `Action` when the user is not logged in using a Custom **Annotation**.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
...
class FooController extends Controller
{
    ...

    /*
    * The code bellow should only be executed if the user 
    * is authorized, otherwise should throw an exception 
    * or something.
    *
    * @Authorized
    */
    public function barAction($cid) {
        // do stuff only if user is authorized
    }

    ...
}
```

I know I could do this using some sort of  "*Decorator Design Pattern*" but what I'd really want is something more like **Python**'s **Decorator** using **PHP** **Annotations**

**Is this posible? How would I do it?**

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle) you can [annotate the controller class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html). From their example,

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Another alternative is the [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) to [secure your service layer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html#securing-methods-using-annotations), e.g.,

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Newsletter;

use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
// ...

class NewsletterManager
{

    /**
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_NEWSLETTER_ADMIN")
     */
    public function sendNewsletter()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```